# Pymongo and n-grams search

Tags: python, mongodb, dictionary, reduce, database

I have a collection of documents in mongo db. I am using Pymongo to access and insert into this collection. What I want to do is :

In python, use map reduce to efficiently query the number of times a n -gram phrase is used across the entire corpus.

I know how to do this for single words, but struggling to extend it to n-grams. What I dont want to do is tokenize using the NLTK library and then run map reduce. I believe that will take the efficiency out of the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an efficient system, you'll need to break down the n-grams ahead of time and index them. When I wrote the [5-Gram Experiment](http://5gram.labix.org) (unfortunately the backend is offline now as I had to give back the hardware), I've created a map of `word => integer id`, and then stored in MongoDB a hex id sequence in the document key field of a collection (for example, `[10, 2] => "a:2"`). Then, randomly distributing the ~350 million 5-grams to 10 machines running MongoDB offered sub-second query times for the whole data set.

You can a similar scheme. With a document such as:

```
{_id: "a:2", seen: [docId1, docId2, ...]}
```

You'll be able to find where the given n-gram was found.

**Update:** Actually, a small correction: in the system that went live I ended up using the same scheme, but encoding the n-gram keys in a binary format for space efficiency (~350M is a *lot* of 5-grams!), but otherwise the mechanics were all the same.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on *stored in MongoDB a hex id sequence in the document key field of a collection*? What is this hex id sequence, and how is that related to `[10, 2] => "a:2"`?

Comment: The details are not so relevant. The important idea was simply encoding the set of ordered integers that identified the specific word in a short amount of space for efficiency across the system. The final system even used a binary format for that encoding, rather than hex.